# Leaflet overlapping markers - displaying popups?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a geojson layer that has over 100 points, and some of them are at the same coordinate position.

When clicking on an icon that has overlapping features, the popup only displays the last added marker to the map.

Is there a way to read all features from the same marker position, and then group the information into a single popup?

Adding geojson features:-

```
var mapFeatures = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Feature 1"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.303197, 51.408362]
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Feature 2"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-0.303197, 51.408362]
    }
}];
```

...and adding the layer to the map with a binded popup...

```
L.geoJSON(mapFeatures, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
            }
}).addTo(map);
```

[A basic fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/ch6td7kw/) showing a simple example with two overlapping markers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it's not exact answer of your problem because you can't really add multiple marker's details on the same polygon if it's overlapping.

What I can suggest alternatively is to use [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) which will give you a neat view of markers in case of overlapping.

Another way is you can use [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) to deal with overlapping markers in Google Earth-style.

That's an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-leaflet-markercluster?file=index.ts) of someone used markercluster which will give you a basic idea.